# How to use Link component to go to another page with onClick attribute?

Tags: reactjs

Hello guys I have the following button where I make an order but after I get the response from `handleSubmit()` I want to go on `/order` page.

```
<Link
    to="/order"
    onClick={this.handleSubmit}
    className="FormField__Button_Order"
    style={{
      textDecoration: "none",
      color: "#433969"
    }}
    >
    Order Now
</Link>
```

Comment: pls add the code for `handleSubmit()` to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is using `onClick` in `<Link />`, solution:-

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends React.Component{
    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        this.props.history.push('/order');
    }
    render(){
        return(
        <button onClick={(event) => this.handleSubmit(event)}>Order Now</button>        
    }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

`to use history as a props in this component, wrap componentName with withRouter`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a button to call handle submit then use the Redirect component to redirect to your page: [Redirecting in React](https://medium.com/@anneeb/redirecting-in-react-4de5e517354a)

```
import React from 'react'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
class MyComponent extends React.Component {  
    state = {
        redirect: false
    }
    setRedirect = () => {
      this.setState({
        redirect: true
      })
    }
  renderRedirect = () => {
    if (this.state.redirect) {
      return <Redirect to='/target' push />
    }
  }
  render () {
    return (
       <div>
        {this.renderRedirect()}
        <button type='button' onClick={this.setRedirect}>Redirect</button>
       </div>
    )
  }
}
```